# How Do I take time in current format in console App

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I have a console app where I need to compare date and time and need to fire emails.

To compare dates:

```
if ((String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", thisresult.schedule_StartDate)) == String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
```

It is working fine. But Now I need to put `&&` condition here and compare time also. In database I have time stored as `nvarchar`. I have data like this stored in database: **10 : 00**.

For this I tried to do like below:

```
if ((String.Format("{0:mm}", thisresult.schedule_starttime)) == String.Format("{0:mm}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
```

But this condition is not working. So how can I take time in specified format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you said that you have data like this stored in database: 10 : 00 then try

```
if (thisresult.schedule_starttime.Replace(" ","") == DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"))
```

`Replace` only works if schedule_starttime is string . As you said  schedule_starttime is varchar, if not then first convert to string and then compare.

Comment: Hi i tried your answer but not working. In debug, i can see in thisresult.schedule_starttime, results as "11:58". I think here i have in string format,so thats why its not taking.

Comment: I added spaces between hour and minute remove that and try.

Answer (score 2):

Compare `DateTime`s not `String`s.

To compare the `DateTime` use `DateTime.Today`:

```
thisresult.schedule_StartDate == DateTime.Today
```

for the `TimeSpan` use `DateTime.TimeOfDay`:

```
thisresult.schedule_starttime == DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty much what Tim wrote. Take value from DB and parse it as DateTime and then compare two DateTime's.

Comment: Hi tim is this correct ? if ( thisresult.schedule_starttime == String.Format("{0:mm}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)) . I tried like this but still it is not taking.

Comment: if (thisresult.schedule_starttime.Date == DateTime.Today) { ... }

Comment: If `schedule_starttime` is a `TimeSpan` you don't need to convert it to a string at all. That's the whole point of my answer. I now see that you are storing it as `varchar`. That's a great problem in your model. I would solve that first. Otherwise always casting to `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` is your smallest problem.